# Is matrix concatenation backwards in Android?

Tags: java, android

I would expect (based on intuition, and the implementation of [`AffineTransform`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) in Java):

```
a.postConcat(b) ->  a = a x b  
a.preConcat(b) -> a = b x a
```

but according to the android documentation:

```
public boolean preConcat (Matrix other)
```

Preconcats the matrix with the specified matrix. M' = M x other

```
public boolean postConcat (Matrix other)
```

Postconcats the matrix with the specified matrix. M' = other x M

This seems backwards to me, am I missing something?

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: Isn't this like the (in)famous string.join(iterable) in Python? :)

Comment: In `AffineTransform`, `concat()` plays the role of your hypothetical `postConcat()`.

Comment: this is my point, in AffineTransform, concat() plays rule of my hypothetical postConcat(), which is the same as Matrix's preConcat(). Which seems backwards.  Which is why I was wondering if I was missing something...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the method 'post concat' is called so because the transformation, which the matrix `other` describes, is performed **after** the transformation matrix `M` stands for.